# NSURLSession: "Background URL session needs events handled"

Tags: ios, nsurlsession

I'm performing an upload task in the background with NSURLSession.  I keep seeing this message in the output: "Background URL session needs events handled"  Where should I be handling the event for this?  In the app delegate, in the class with my networking code?  What exactly do I need to do?

Comment: Did you implement `handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession` in your app delegate? Did you save the `completionHandler`? Do you call it in in `URLSessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession` (or some point soon thereafter)?